# recv() correct use C++

Tags: c++, loops, recv

I'm working on my own FTP client in C++, but I'm stuck at function **recv()**. When I get data with recv(), they can be incomplete, because I'm using **TCP** protocol, so I have to use recv in **loop**. Problem is that when I call recv after everything that should be received was received server **blocks**, and my program is stuck. 
I don't know how many bytes im going to recieve so I can't control it and stop it when its done. I found two not very elegant solutions right now:

1. is to use string.substr() (or TR1 regex) to find needed
   expression and then stop calling recv before it blocks
2. second is to
       set up timeval structure and then control socket through 
       setsockopt() function. Problem is long response time when i can get
       incomplete corrupted data.

*Question is, is there any clean and elegant solution for this?*

Comment: you can use boost for all your tcp needs, especially boost::asio

Comment: since TCP is a stream of bytes, any structure must be provided by the process using it.  The [OSI network model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) provides a basic concept for the various layers that are needed.

Comment: On which operating system? a Posix one (Linux)? standard C++ does not know about sockets.

Comment: Linux, yes , classic sockets from sys/socket.h and functions from netdb.h

Comment: what I have done in the past is to have a thread using recv() to get data that is then made available to a stream input parsing function.  The stream input parsing function provides complete data blocks to the caller.  If recv() blocks due to no more data yet there is sufficient data for an entire data block then the stream input parsing function will return with the data block while recv() is blocking.  If you want to do this in a single thread, you will need to use asynchronous I/O and do a check against the socket to see if data is available using select().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious thing to do is to transmit the length of the to-be-received message ahead (many protocols, including for example HTTP do that, to address the exact same issue). That way, you know that when you have received amount X, no more will come.

This will work fine 99.9% of the time and will catastrophically fail in the 0.1% of cases where the server is lying to you or where the server crashes unexpectedly or someone stumbles over the network cable (or something similar happens). Sadly, the "connection" established by TCP is an illusion, and you don't have much of a means to detect when the connection dies. The other end can go down, and you will not notice anything, unless you try to send and get an error (or until several hours later).

Therefore, you also need a backup strategy for when things don't go quite as good as expected. You might either use `select` or `poll` to know when data is available, so you don't block forever for a message that will never come.

Using threads to solve the block-at-end problem (as proposed in other answers) is not a very good option since blocking isn't the *actual* problem. The actual problem is that you don't know when you have reached the end of the transmission. Having a worker thread block at the end of the transmission will "work", but will leave the worker thread blocked indefinitely, consuming resources and with an uncertain, system-dependent fate.

You cannot `join` the thread before exiting, since it is blocked (so trying to `join` it would deadlock your main thread). When your process exits and the socket is closed, the thread will unblock, but will (at least on *some* operating systems, e.g. Windows) be terminated immediately after. This likely won't do much evil, but terminating a thread in an uncontrolled way is always less desirable than having it exit properly. On other operating systems, you may have a lingering thread remaining.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++, there are alternative libraries that greatly simplify network programming compared to stock C. My personal favourite is [Boost::Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), however others are available. These libraries not only save you the pain of coding in C, but also provide asynchronous capabilities to work around your blocking problem.

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach is to use `select()`/`pselect()` or `poll()`/`ppoll()`. Both allow to specify a timeout in order to exit if there are no incoming data.

However I don't see how you should "call recv after everything that should be received". It would be extremely inefficient to rely on the timeout also when there are not network problems...

Or you send the size of data being sent, before the data, and that's what you read, or the data connection is terminated with an EOF. In this case read() will return -1 and you exit.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options that will not require a major rewrite of your existing code and a third one which is more radical:

1. use [non-blocking I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) and poll for data periodically. You can do other work while a message remains incomplete or no further data can be read from the socket.
2. use a separate worker thread to do the I/O. Even if it blocks on synchronous recv() calls, your main thread can continue to do work. The worker thread can transfer the data it receives to the main thread for processing once a complete message is received via TCP.
3. use an OS specific feature (I/O completion ports on Windows or aio on Linux), but these are far more complex and you should definitely consider [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) before going this route.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the recv function in it's own thread and do the processing in another thread.